# React router dom Link makes the image gone

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, frontend

I have 4 React components but only one component that has an image. I'm using `react-router-dom` and `Link` to move to another page. I had this navbar that link to every component. Somehow whenever I clicked to return to `home` component that has an `image`, suddenly the image is gone. This is what I'm doing :

`home (has an image) > about > services > home (the images gone)`

I've seen the source with `developer tools` and the image is still there but It just it won't showing

**EDIT**

adding some resource :

Navbar.jsx

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

export default class Navbar extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <nav role="navigation" style={{ backgroundColor: "#00a3ff" }}>
        <div className="nav-wrapper container">
          <a id="logo-container" href="#" className="brand-logo">
            <i className="material-icons">accessible_forward</i>
          </a>
          <small style={{ marginLeft: "3%" }}>Jompow</small>

          <ul className="right hide-on-med-and-down">
            <li>
              <Link to="/">Utama</Link>
            </li>
            <li>
              <Link to="/tentang">Tentang Kami</Link>
            </li>
            <li>
              <Link to="/kontak">Kontak</Link>
            </li>
            <li>
              <Link to="/layanan">Layanan</Link>
            </li>
          </ul>

          <ul id="nav-mobile" className="sidenav">
            <li>
              <Link to="/">Utama</Link>
            </li>
            <li>
              <Link to="/tentang">Tentang Kami</Link>
            </li>
            <li>
              <Link to="/kontak">Kontak</Link>
            </li>
            <li>
              <Link to="/layanan">Layanan</Link>
            </li>
          </ul>
          <a href="#" data-target="nav-mobile" className="sidenav-trigger">
            <i className="material-icons">menu</i>
          </a>
        </div>
      </nav>
    );
  }
}
```

Home.jsx

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";

export default class Main extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
        <div id="index-banner" className="parallax-container">
          <div className="section no-pad-bot">
            <div className="container">
              <br />
              <br />
              <h1 className="header center teal-text text-lighten-2">
                Jompa Jampi
              </h1>
              <div className="row center">
                <h5 className="header col s12 light">
                  Tempat kumpul kongkow panti Jompo haipe bist!
                </h5>
              </div>
              <div className="row center">
                <a
                  id="download-button"
                  className="btn-large waves-effect waves-light teal lighten-1"
                  role="button"
                >
                  Click for nothing!
                </a>
              </div>
              <br />
              <br />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="parallax">
            <img src="/img/background3.jpg" alt="Unsplashed background img 1" />
            <div className="overlay"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I believe there is insufficient information in your question. Please add code sample that reproduces the problem

Comment: I'm not sure which one should I add, App.js or the Navbar

Comment: In that case please add both

Comment: Share your home component source code

Comment: I added some of the home.jsx section

Comment: Can you add the code in the code sandbox? Then we could find the issue as well.

Comment: that will takes too long. I was just wondering if it's the react-router-dom problems or should I use `a href` instead to link the component

Comment: Can you please put here the code where you put all of your `<Route/>`?